# Div css auto adjust height to content dynamically

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a div with auto height and adjustable textarea. I wanted the parent div to auto expand/collapse depending on the content.

To recreate the problem in Chrome:

1. Re-size the textbox downwards to increase the height of the parent div
2. Re-size the textbox back to its inital position. You will see that the parent height does not retract.

*Text area being draggable is just a representation for a select2 box.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wugwxc7u/) of the below:

```css
#parent {
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div>
 <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
</div>
```

How do I get the div to retract/collapse back to initial height after the text area is collapsed?

Comment: Explain yourself. what initial height? what do you mean collapsed? which "content"? non of this is in your code...

Comment: @misterManSam - I can't drag anything there. [disclosure: using IE :-) ]

Comment: @Amit - True, IE wont resize the textarea. This seems to be a problem in Chrome only (Firefox can resize but the parent does retract)

Comment: Milo - Are you using Chrome?

Comment: @Milo Cabs can you please explain what do mean by your code...?

Comment: yup im using chrome. yes drag the text area to expand/collapse

Comment: thanks @misterManSam for editing

Answer (score 0):

I've added relevant Javascript code to your **jsfiddle** for the required functionality, check out the link:

[Auto Fill Textarea](https://jsfiddle.net/wugwxc7u/1/)

```js
var autoExpandTextArea = function (textAreaName, maxRows, minRows) {
    var textarea = document.getElementById(textAreaName);
    var limitRows = maxRows;
    if(textarea === null || minRows > maxRows)
        return;
  
    var commonEventHandlerCode = function(textAreaA, limitRowsB, scrollHeightC)
    {
        var rows = parseInt(textAreaA.getAttribute("rows"));
            if (rows < limitRowsB && textAreaA.scrollHeight > scrollHeightC) {
                rows++;
            } else if (rows > 1 && textAreaA.scrollHeight < scrollHeightC) {
                rows--;
            }

            scrollHeightC = textAreaA.scrollHeight;
            textAreaA.setAttribute("rows", rows);
    };
   
    textarea.setAttribute("rows", minRows);
    var messageLastScrollHeight = textarea.scrollHeight;
    if ($.browser == "MSIE") {
        $(textarea).keyup = function () {
            commonEventHandlerCode(textarea, limitRows, messageLastScrollHeight);
        };
    } else {
        textarea.oninput = function () {
            commonEventHandlerCode(textarea, limitRows, messageLastScrollHeight);
        };
    }
};
autoExpandTextArea("textarea", 4, 2);
```

```css
#parent{
    background-color:green;
    -webkit-column-count:2;
}
```

```html
<div id="textarea">
    <div><textarea></textarea></div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some sort of expanation about what the javascript is doing. But, **this doesn't seem to work...** the parent still does not retract.

Comment: well, in brief, I've added an event listener, checking on textarea's height and textarea's scroll height, so if it's lower than the contents height, there goes an increment to the rows, and if it's higher , there's goes a decrements .... and yes, it does retract if you don't expand the textarea, however, i'm working on a better solution with expanded textarea!

Answer (score 0):

Your parent div(#textarea) will be resized automatically if you do not give fixed height. if you want to resize only vertically than try using -

```
textarea {
    resize: vertical;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: My concern is on the parent div and how to make it go back to an original height after the textarea is contracted.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `contenteditable` attribute as a replacement for the textarea. It will behave as a normal block element (thus expands on more content) but than it is editable. Downside is that it needs javascript to add it's contents to a form field so it can be posted to a server.

See [this edited fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wugwxc7u/5/) for an example.
EDIT: added an example of how the editable can collapse to it's initial size after editing.

Comment: im not actually using a textarea. i just showed it to represent a select2 box. just wondering how to resize the parent div back when the content is contracted.

Comment: See the new fiddle: I'm not sure if this is the behavior you want, but it will hopefully give an idea how you can collapse the editable back to it's original size.

Comment: yes it collapses but the parent div in green still doesnt

Comment: The parent will collapse back if you set `overflow: hidden;` on `#editable`. But that means you can't  scroll the content but that you always have to click/expand it. Is this acceptable? Otherwise I will think of a better solution.

Comment: not really since it needs to expand for the content to be seen.

Answer (score 0):

There are many bugs with CSS columns distribution and that is probably the reason Masonry is used a lot.

You can try to force webkit browsers to re-render the columns on textarea input or resize. Another problem is: webkit won't trigger resize event on textarea, so you need to define that too:

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
 /* Chrome does not trigger textarea resize: */
 $('textarea').each(function (i) {
  var thisTextarea = $(this);
  thisTextarea.data('x', thisTextarea.outerWidth());
  thisTextarea.data('y', thisTextarea.outerHeight());
  thisTextarea.on('mouseup', function (e) {
   if (thisTextarea.outerWidth() != thisTextarea.data('x') || thisTextarea.outerHeight() != thisTextarea.data('y')) {
    thisTextarea.trigger('resize');
   };
   thisTextarea.data('x', thisTextarea.outerWidth());
   thisTextarea.data('y', thisTextarea.outerHeight());
  });
 });

 var colContainer = $('#parent');
 $('textarea').on('input resize', function (e) {
  colContainer.css({
   '-webkit-column-count': '1'
  });
  setTimeout(function () {
   colContainer.css({
    '-webkit-column-count': '2'
   });
  }, 0);
 });
});
```

```css
#parent {
    background-color: green;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="parent">
    <div>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
</div>
```

**[Playground Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wugwxc7u/7/)**

Comment: good workaround. but i can't do this since there could be a case that all of the content would be a textarea. I think its overkill to add that kind of logic to each field.

Comment: not sure what you did but the parent background isnt resizing back anymore

Answer (score 0):

I use some jquery to match heights.

For example.

```
function equalHeight() {
    //Checks if the leftside height is bigger           
    if ($(".leftside:visible").height() >= $(".rightside:visible").height()) { 
        $(".rightside:visible").height($(".leftside:visible").height());        

        //  alert("Changing to leftside height");
    } else {
        //Change leftside height to the current rightside
        $(".leftside:visible").height($(".rightside:visible").height());

        //alert("Changing to rightside height");
    }
}
```